# Parallelism for global window with stateful DoFn on unbounded collection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am reading documentation about stateful functions in Apache Beam and I don't understand some parts of it.

I found that [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing-basics) if I will not assign any window to PCollection it means that global window will be used by default.

> Note that even if you don’t set a windowing function, there is still a window – all elements in your PCollection are assigned to a single global window.

After that I read this [article](https://beam.apache.org/blog/stateful-processing/) about stateful processing in Apache Beam. I found here that default parallelization for stateful function will be done per key and window.

> A state cell in Beam is scoped to a key+window pair.

Am I right in case of usage of unbounded collection with ten unique keys for example I will have ten separate stateful PTransform for each key with infinite state, right?